# Twitter Update status throwing exception

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using this class to fetch the oAuth token from twitter and trying to update the status.
http://twitteroauth.labs.poseurtech.com/connect.php

I am able to generate the oAuth token from my local system and can even update the status through it.But when I put the same code on server it is throwing one error,which is :

> stdClass Object (
>       [error] => Invalid / used nonce )

I can not understand why this used **nonce error** is coming. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Make sure nonce is different for each request. For a better answer, please provide some code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the time is correct on your server and your requests are properly encoded?